# Declare custom object with relationships

Tags: apex, custom-object, relationships

*Beginner disclaimer*
Apologies if this seems stupid but I've been a bit stumped by this. I have looked through documentation but cannot find the answer I need to here I am.

I have a custom object called Commission. It is related to Contact via a master-detail relationship called Awarded To.

When declaring a new commission (in a test class in my case) do I need to define both the __r and __c of the new object?

```
// Test data setup
Account acct = new Account(Name='Test Account');
insert acct;
Contact cont = new Contact(LastName='Doe', Primary__c=false,AccountId=acct.Id);
insert cont;    

Test.startTest();
Commission__c comm = new Commission__c(Amount__c=2000);
comm.Awarded_To__r = cont;
comm.Awarded_To__c = cont.Id;
insert comm;
Test.stopTest();
```

On another note; should I name the relationship "Contact" rather than "Awarded To"? What is the best practice convention here?

Comment: only set the comm.Awarded_To__c is enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't specify both `__r` and `__c` variants on a record like this. This is because the `__r` variant tells Saleforce that you want to associate a record by an External ID, while the `__c` variant tells Salesforce that you want to associate a record by ID. Consider this code:

```
Contact c = new Contact(LastName='Doe', Account=new Account(External_Id__c='Demo 123'));
insert c;
```

In this code, I create a new Contact that is linked to the Account with an External ID of 'Demo 123'. If there is not exactly one matching record, this code instead throws an exception.

---

In the case of the unit test, you ordinarily only need to set the `__c` value. There are times you might want to set the `__r` value instead, such as in a Visualforce page controller where the values for the related record are specified in the markup, and you want to emulate that in your unit test:

```
Account a = new Account(Name='Demo');
insert a;
Contact c = new Contact(AccountId=a.Id, LastName='Demo');
insert c;
Commission__c com = new Commission__c(Awarded_To__r=c, Amount__c=5000);
ApexPages.StandardController stdCtrl = new ApexPages.StandardController(com);
MyVFPageController controller = new MyVFPageController(stdCtrl);
// .. more logic here
```

Therefore, there are times you might want to initialize `__r`, or even both of them, but only when the code you're testing needs it, which is usually pretty rare.

---

> On another note; should I name the relationship "Contact" rather than "Awarded To"? What is the best practice convention here?

The field's name should be a description of what its describing. As a standard system example, check out `Contact.ReportsToId`. Here, this field is referencing a Contact object, but we call it `ReportsTo`/`ReportsToId`. In the UI, the field's label is `Reports To`, and indicates the person's direct manager (at least, this is the intent of this field).

Often, the object name and field name will happen to correspond to each other (see `Contact.AccountId` as an example), but it doesn't need to be. I think the industry norm would be to call it `AwardedTo__c` (or `Awarded_To__c`), since that's is what the field is describing; the person to whom the commission was awarded to. It's typically better to have a descriptive name than one that describes the object you're referencing, especially if you'd otherwise have a discrepancy between the label and field name, or an ambiguous field label.

Imagine you're looking at a Commission record. Would it be clearer to say "Contact" or "Awarded To"? The former only describes that it's a contact record, but the latter informs the user that this commission was awarded to that contact. This is a much better description so users don't have to guess the intent.

Similarly, given a field label of "Awarded To", would it be better to call it `Contact__c` or `Awarded_To__c`? Any competent/experienced developer is going to naturally presume that the field is named `AwardedTo__c` or `Awarded_To__c`, but definitely **not** `Contact__c`.

You could do this, but the more "naming exceptions" you have, the harder it will be for developers to work with this later, as they'll have to consult the metadata/documentation to know what field they're looking for. It'd be best to have the name match the label.

Comment: Thank you @sfdcfox. Following on from this. I want to traverse the relationship from the commission object to its account parent object, to find its ID. How do I do this? I thought it should be commissionObject.Awarded_To__r.AccountId but it returning null for me.

Comment: @gpcurran Inside the unit test, assuming you specify just the `__c` field, the `__r` would not contain any data. You'd want to query the record first. You might want to post a new question, and perhaps we could help you out with your problem?